# Cant allow app to control computer anymore

Tags: macos, security, accessibility, privacy

I'm developing app now, and when I debug it - I open debug folder and drag app into Preferences->Privacy->Accessibility->List. When I want to show demo, I drag this app to applications folder and remove old app from accessibility and add new one from applications.

Today I can't drag nor add by + this app.

So, I open console. Drag again - nothing. Add via +, see next messages:

```
25/12/14 16:27:21,228 WindowServer[143]: window 103 is already attached to window a0 
25/12/14 16:27:21,824 WindowServer[143]: window 103 is already attached to window a0
25/12/14 16:27:21,837 WindowServer[143]: window 103 is already attached to window a0
25/12/14 16:27:23,602 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[868]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
25/12/14 16:27:25,072 WindowServer[143]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x103 requiring rights 0x5 by caller System Preferences
```

In accessibility I already have Automator, Script editor (not checked), Xcode (probably they was meaned in first three lines).

I worry about last one - have no idea what it talks about? Are my rights has been gone somehow? Funny, but I am able to add any other product to that list...

Comment: Is your question about the windowserver ? it says that action is already ongoing.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I'm new to mac, so I don't understand what do you mean. My question is "why i cant drag my app". 
Where and what I can take a look to answer your question?

Comment: Any that you do not want just remove the check box mark. I do not understand the reason for your Console log ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No. I enumerated apps which are in list already. I want DRAG myApp there. Into Accessibility on yosemite. But mac doesn't display myApp there, when I drag myApp there. It just ignores it. When I use chooseFileDialog way, I see error in system logs. I just think these logs will point a way. It says "you need 0x5 rights", but I dont know what is this, and how it could be broken, cause yesterday myApp didn't been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142298/apps-stuck-in-security-privacy-accessibility?rq=1) answer I made a select query to Tcc.db, and I see myApp there, despite that I don't see them in window. Actually, I have tried to delete database before writing my question, but still problems have been occured, so I desided then app has no access to mac.

But, when I delete from DB myApp, then select query - all gone, OK. 
Then drag again, then select query execute - myApp appeared with same settings as other apps, but still invisible in in privacy.